# How to reproduce this cURL request using Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, curl, resttemplate

I am trying to achieve GET request calls containing a request body. Yeah, I know. So here is my problem.

I have a Spring MVC controller responding fine to the following pseudo-command:

```
curl  -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:9098/a/{aID}/b/{bID}/c -d '{"header":{"foo":"foofoofoo","timestamp":"2015-06-23T03:45:43-04:00"}}'
```

I am trying to reproduce this call from another spring mvc app using *RestTemplate.exchange*, but keep getting a 400 bad request error on the client side app -- the server side application doesn't seem to log any error regarding the call.

The client side controller

```
@GET
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/a/{aID}/b/{bID}/c")
public String getC(
        @PathParam(value = "aID") String aId,
        @PathParam(value = "bID") String bId) {

    ResponseEntity<String> result = null;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(serverApplicationUrlLocalhost9098);
    url.append("/a/").append(aId);
    url.append("/b/").append(bId);
    url.append("/c");
    String finalUrl = url.toString();
    try {

        org.springframework.http.MediaType mediaType = org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;

        List<org.springframework.http.MediaType> accepts = new ArrayList<org.springframework.http.MediaType>();
        accepts.add(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(accepts);
        headers.setContentType(mediaType);

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        HttpEntity<Foo> request = new HttpEntity<Foo>(foo, headers);


        result = restTemplate.exchange(finalUrl, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error calling REST service: " + finalUrl, e);
    }

    return result.getBody();
}
```

For the purpose of testing, I have a private class Foo

```
   private class Header {
    private String foo = "foofoofoo";
    private String timestamp = "2015-06-23T03:45:43-04:00";
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo =  foo;
    }
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }


}


private class Foo {
    private Header header = new Header();

    public Header getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(Header header) {
        this.header = header;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that the body represented by `Foo` class will be serialized as `{"foo":"foofoofoo","timestamp":"2015-06-23T03:45:43-04:00"}` and not `{"header":{"foo":"foofoofoo","timestamp":"2015-06-23T03:45:43-04:00"}}` as in your curl command, which might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Wow, I missed that one for sure. I changed the code but nothing seems to have changed. Same bad request error.